# Agregar valores a cada clave en un diccionario Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una duda que espero me puedan ayudar a resolver.

Tengo una lista, que quiero pasar a un diccionario, la cual es la siguiente:

```
lista=[["q0","a","q1"],["q0","a","q0"],["q0","b","q0"],["q1","a","q0"],["q2","a","q1"],["q1","a","q2"], ["q2","b","q0"]]
```

El diccionario debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
dict={
("q0","a"):["q1","q0"],
("q0","b"):["q0"],
("q1","a"):["q0","q2"],
("q2","a"):["q1"],
("q2","b"):["q0"]
}
```

**NOTA: es la estructura de un AFN**

Como pueden ver, la clave del diccionario son los primeros 2 términos de cada sublista [0:2], y el valor de cada clave es el último término de cada sublista [-1].
El problema aquí es ¿cómo puedo añadir varios valores a la misma clave?
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Se los agradecería mucho.

**NOTA: Es importante no usar colecciones**

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres una solución sin listas, ni set, ni numpy, ni pandas?

Comment: ¿Por qué es importante no usar colecciones? (entiendo que te refieres al módulo `collections`) Es un módulo que forma parte del lenguaje ¿por qué no usarlo? Te ayudará a simplificar el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución simple:

```
dicc = {}
for sublista in lista:
    key = (sublista[0], sublista[1])
    value = sublista[2]
    if key not in dicc:
        dicc[key] = []
    dicc[key].append(value)
```

La solución recorre la lista de sublistas. De cada una se sacan los dos primeros valores para formar la tupla que será la llave.

El valor asociado a cada llave es una lista. La lista se crea vacia al detectarse una nueva llave.

**Demo**

```
for k, v in dicc.items():
    print(k, v)
```

produce:

```
('q0', 'a') ['q1', 'q0']
('q0', 'b') ['q0']
('q1', 'a') ['q0', 'q2']
('q2', 'a') ['q1']
('q2', 'b') ['q0']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Justo lo que necesitaba.